# After popToRootViewController swiping back is disabled

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swipe

When swiping from the left edge to the right, you`ll get back to the previous view.

But after calling

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

or...

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

... then swiping back (in any view) is not possible anymore. Only the back-button works. It only works when deleting the app from multitasking and relaunching the app.
How can i solve this?

Comment: How does the back button work if you popped to root? There is nowhere to go back to...

Comment: I mean, in the whole app i can not swipe back anymore

Comment: so push, swipe works, push, pop & push again and swipe doesn't work ?

Comment: no, after calling any of the 2 methods, the swiping doesnt work in any of my views in the whole app. it only works when deleting the app from multitasking and relaunching

Comment: If you call `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];`, it will go to the very first of view controller (the one at the bottom of the navigation stack) so that you can't go back or swipe back simply because there is no view controller to go back. However for `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`, it works perfectly to me. Both swipe gesture and back button is working.

Comment: Ok, lets say i have 3 views: i am pushing from view 1 to view 2.then from view 2 to view 3. afer deleting a row in view 3 i call poptorootviewcontroller...now i am in view 1...fine...when i push now from view 1 to view 2 and i do a swipe in view 2, nothing happens. the same happens with popviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Now it works!
I used the following code in viewWillDisappear to reenable swipe gesture

```
if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
    }
```